# 500 server error with servlet after deploy it on app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, eclipse-plugin

please take a look to my problem below i deployed my website (java) on my app engine account the url it work to show html and jsp pages but the servlet pages it make error rather than show it correctly this is what appear:

> Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could
>   not complete your request. If the problem persists, please report your
>   problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

notice :: that all work on localhost server but on app engine !! what can i
do to avoid this problem !!!!

Comment: We could not possibly answer you with such a limited amount of information. Post more details about the problem that you encountered. Stacktraces or code snippets would also be useful.

Comment: i install on my pc Netbeans  ,,is it possible reason for my problem cause it run apache server ???

Comment: Locally running server should not be a problem in after deployment, since your app is hosted in the App Engine server. Could you go to your [app engine dashboard](https://appengine.google.com/), select your app, and see what it says about the Server Error in the Logs menu on the left side of your dashboard page?

Comment: from log 

Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@1bbc779{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~hanajust2008/1.356904243569237819}
org.mortbay.util.MultiException[java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: web/ASS2webServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: web/Iss : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0]

Comment: 2012-02-18 08:22:38.747
Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed.

Comment: 2012-02-18 08:22:38.750
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.

Comment: W 2012-02-17 04:30:58.415 Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@b6a6d6{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~hanajust2008/1.3568800512284
C 2012-02-17 04:30:58.422 Uncaught exception from servlet javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed. at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMa
I 2012-02-17 04:30:58.425 This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This requ

Answer (score 2):

web/ASS2webServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Indicates that you are using a higher version of Java than GAE supports. Quoting from documentation of GAE:

"App Engine runs Java applications using the Java 6 virtual machine (JVM). The App Engine SDK supports Java 5 and later, and the Java 6 JVM can use classes compiled with any version of the Java compiler up to Java 6"

So can you check what version are you using on local Eclipse to compile your classes?

Comment: i have java 7 running on my compiler >> so i need to install java 6

Comment: Yes. You can change compiler settings within Eclipse for that project too

Comment: when i remove java 7 and install java 6 
the projects didn't run correctly !!!! although i change the java compiler of the project to 1.6

Comment: this from my console window :


java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to restore the previous TimeZone
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restoreLocalTimeZone(DevAppServerImpl.java:228)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:164)
 at

Comment: com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:164)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:113)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:89)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: defaultZoneTL
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restoreLocalTimeZone(DevAppServerImpl.java:222)
 ... 5 more

Comment: The issue is with specific version of JDK: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6928 , try with jdk 1.6 u30 or lower!

Comment: You would want to accept this as the "right answer" by clicking on Right sign : http://www.featurepics.com/FI/Thumb/20101227/Right-Sign-1743733.jpg :)

Comment: oooooooooooooooh ,, no
the problem return again :(

Comment: just when i open my app from my google app engine account it work but otherwise it didn't work

Comment: code is a simple servlet just class from servlet and print any word
BUT the error is the same above when the url taken the srvlet

Comment: You are still doing something wrong with version if error is same. You will have to apply the change

Comment: this problem not appeared when i opened my app engine account and try get the url from there 
but when my account off this problem appeared !!!!
 i don't know from what that cause this !!!!!!!!!!!